# VSCode - Source Control Coloring

Tags: visual-studio-code, color-scheme, ide-customization

So by default if a change is made, VSCode Source Control sets a blue marker on the file and all directories that contain the changes.

And it also colors the names, which for me in some situations, seems a bit distracting in bigger applications.

**Is there a way to customize this, so the Folder and File names do not change color and only the small Markers on the right remain ?**

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `"explorer.decorations.colors"` setting, you can turn off all colors on the text, while still maintaining the "Modified" indicator.  This turns off all coloring, but I think really the only coloring I've seen so far comes from Git tracking changes, and if problems are detected in files - those are probably the most common forms of coloring at least.

For example, with `"explorer.decorations.colors"` set to `false,`:

[image: Json settings]

You can also set `"git.decorations.enabled"` to `false`, but you will lose the indicator as well.

Comment: Thank you Timothy, this was exactly what i was looking for, worked perfectly.